# Memory issue while trying to save huge data in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, database, uiimage

I am trying to save multiple images to my documents directory after capturing them from the camera. Its about 50 images that I am trying to save. But the app crashes every time I try to save them since the images are too many and I receive memory warning. I have no clue on how to tackle this problem. 
Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i<_arrImages.count; i++)
{

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^
               {
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *dateStringId = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];


[Utils saveImage:image withName:dateStringId toFolder:kImageFolder];



UIImage *thumbImage = [image imageCroppedAndScaledToSize:CGSizeMake(150, 112) contentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill padToFit:YES];

[Utils saveImage:thumbImage withName:dateStringId toFolder:kThumbnailFolder];


NSMutableDictionary *sendDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[sendDict setObject:dateStringId forKey:kitemId];
[sendDict setObject:@"image" forKey:kitemType];
[sendDict setObject:[Utils getPathForImageName:dateStringId ofFolder:kImageFolder] forKey:kitemPath];
[sendDict setObject:kStatusUnused forKey:kitemStatus];
[sendDict setObject:dateString forKey:kitemDate];
[sendDict setObject:[Utils getPathForImageName:dateStringId ofFolder:kThumbnailFolder] forKey:kitemThumb];


[SCDatabaseHandler insertIntoMainTableValues:sendDict];
               });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't show where `image` is coming from, but you shouldn't have all images in memory at the same time.

Instead of using `dispatch_async`, use an instance of `NSOperationQueue` and set the maximum number of concurrent operations to 1 or 2. The block executed by the operations on the queue should load and save the image so you only have one or two images in memory at any one time.

Comment: I would also suggest wrapping the code in the loop in a `@autoreleaspool`

Comment: Yes I have all the images stored in an array which is causing further problem. How should I use NSOperation queue since I have never used it before? I mean how should I wrap my code in it? I searched around the web for it but the tutorials show a method invocation. How should I add operations to the queue?

Comment: Take a look at the `NSBlockOperation` class.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
solved the problem by using the operation block. Added to queue using addOperationWithBlock:

Saved my day. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @SahilTyagi Instead of using a concurrent queue in your original code or NSOperations and NSOperationQueue, you could have just used a serial dispatch queue. ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of ways like creating NSOperationQueue OR core data to save image as an NSData by converting image like this

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(myUIImage)];
```

OR use autorelease pool like this

```
- (BOOL) getImageWithUrl:(NSString *)url toFile:(NSString *)toFile
    {
        @autoreleasepool
        {
            NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]] ;
            if (data)
            {
                NSError *error ;
                if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:toFile])
                {
                    NSLog(@"Existant %@", toFile) ;
                    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:toFile error:nil] ;
                }
                if ([data writeToFile:toFile options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error]==NO)
                {
                    NSLog(@"@Error creating file-%@ \n", toFile) ;
                    NSLog(@"@Error description-%@ \n", [error localizedDescription]) ;
                    NSLog(@"@Error suggestion-%@ \n", [error localizedRecoverySuggestion]) ;
                    NSLog(@"Error reason-%@", [error localizedFailureReason]) ;
                }
                else
                {
                    return(true) ;
                }
            }
            return(false) ;
        }
    }
```

You can use AFNetworking that manages downloading the image in background thread and caching it. The method to use depends on the requirement of your app. Note: Code is written without compiling or testing. Hope it Helps :)